# The love may begin/begins from here

Tags: verb-forms

> The love may **begin** from here.
>
> The love may **begins** from here.

after "**love**" and "**may**" which form of begin we should use? "begin" or "begins"?

Comment: 'the' is never used for love when you generalize it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Love" is a [third-person singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_person) noun. The tense is Simple Present. So in a sentence

> Love **begins** here.

We use the verb "to begin" in the third-person singular form *begins*, with an "S" at the end. Note that the verb "to begin" is used alone here, with no other verb attached to it.

But in your sentence, the verb "to begin" is attached to **may**, which is a [modal verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs). When we attach a verb to a modal verb, creating a two-word combination, we do not add "s" to the verb:

> Love **may begin** here.